# How do I read audio files with AudioToolbox Framework?

Tags: objective-c, audio, audiotoolbox

I want to read data from wave, mp3, and aiff files and use this data for fft.
AudioToolbox Framework looks good, but there is a lot of different and similar functions and its confusing for me.

Can you help me with list of functions ? So I need to get numberOfFrames, channel, sampleRate, bitRate and array with audioData.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your file, and get property and read.

```
ExtAudioFileRef myfile;
ExtAudioFileOpenURL(yourURL, &myfile);

// after you get a AudioStreamBasicDescription
AudioStreamBasicDescription desc={0};
ExtAudioFileGetProperty(myfile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), &desc);
AudioBufferList *ioData = CreateAudioBuffer(desc);
UInt32 nbFrames = 512;
while(nbFrames != 0)
{
     nbFrames = 512;
     ExtAudioFileRead(myfile, &nbFrames, ioData);
     WorkWithFrame(ioData, nbFrames);
}

ExtAudioFileDispose(myfile);
```

You need to write CreateAudioBuffer with data malloc and WorkWithFrames.

I hope this can help you.